# Ending up with an empty csv file after try to add required rows from csv?

Tags: python, csv

I try to implement simple logic to required rows from original data. I am ending up with an empty csv file. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

[Sample dataset is here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLBxm.png)

sample code is here:

```
with open ('tracksample.csv','r') as inp, open('final.csv','w') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if (row[3] == "0" and row[4] == "0"):
            writer.writerows(row)
```

Any leads will be appreciated and advance thanks.

Comment: Maybe row[3] and row[4] are 0 instead of "0"?

Comment: Thank you, but I try in this way too, no changes. Same result. I really don't know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
p=open('final.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(p)
f=open('sample.csv','r')
for row in csv.reader(f):
    if row==[]:
        continue
    print(row)
    if (row[3] == "0" and row[4] =="0"):
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row) 
    

p.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this too.. but same result. I really don't know whats wrong with this ? Ok I gave one more

Comment: so,```final.csv``` becomes empty right? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yeah... Exactly. It is not writing yet all.

Comment: I've edited my code. I created 2 csv files and tried this. It works for me.(I changed the names of the variables, hope you don't mind)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try write it in another method and may be atleast that should help ...if I find an error with that also... Then may be I'll post it here again with that code... May be then you get an idea regarding my post.

Comment: A2A: Thanks for your concern and kind replies. I tried to implement in my own code. It's because of type. I changed my code with just "0.0" it worked fine for me.